# how to detect if emacs is running in a terminal or a window?

Tags: emacs

I'm hoping to be able to branch on a flag in emacs to detect whether it is running in a terminal or a windowed app (i.e. the OS X Emacs app)

Is there such a flag?

Comment: Of course, Emacs can be running in a terminal *and* as a windowed application, so your question is not fully well defined.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the value of the `window-system` variable. In a terminal, it should be `nil`.

For boolean tests, use the `display-graphic-p` function.